# Automatically press enter key after ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an input field, on the ajax response I get some records in li tag. On every li there is an onclick function `add_values`. I want the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to be automatically pressed when the user clicks on any li tag.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="Search" class="txt_field" onkeyup="key_up_val(this.value);" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function key_up_val(val) {
    if(val.length > 5) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'ajax/google_suggestion.php',
            data:'keyword='+val,  // KEYWORD PASSED VALUE WILL GO TO google_suggestion.php
            success:function(res) {
                if(res != '') {
                    $(".suggestion_div").show();
                    $("#suggestion").html(res).fadeIn();
                } else {
                   $(".suggestion_div").hide();
                    $("#suggestion").hide();
                }
                //alert(res); // RESPONSE
            }
        });
    }
}

function add_val(values){    // this function is used in the ajax request onclick event
    $("#Search").val(values); // add the clicked suggestion the the searched field
    //clickevent();
    $(".txt_field").focus();
    var e = $.Event('keyup');
    e.which = 13; // Character 'A'
    $(".txt_field").trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {which: 13}));
}
```

On ajax response I get :-

```
<li class="tushar morzaria" onclick="add_val('tushar morzaria')">tushar morzaria</li>
<li class="tushar meaning" onclick="add_val('tushar meaning')">tushar meaning</li>
```

I want to automatically press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the text field when the user clicks on any li tag.

Comment: on `li.onclick` can you just run the same code that runs when you press "Enter"?

Comment: on for enter press, i would like to do alert box

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution:

```
function add_val(values) {
    $("#Search").val(values); //add the clicked suggestion to the searched field
    $(".txt_field").focus();
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 13 });
    $(".search_field input").trigger(e);
}
```

This would automatically press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on the click on li tag.